# How to create workflow for sending mail for incomplete tasks

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, task-list, sharepoint-email, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have created one task list.In that list Status,Assigned To, Task column is there.one month time period will be given for every task from created date.If the status column is not changed as completed  within one month , the assigned to person should get the mail with the task name and "your task is not completed".
How to create workflow for that using sharepoint designer.I am using sharepoint designer 2010,sharepoint 2016 onpremise.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following workflow:
[image]

1.First we need to add a variable (end date):

[image]

2.Then set the variable value as Start date +30 days, when Today=end date and the status is not equal to "Completed",  it will send mail to people assigned to. (Add a step: send a mail, then select people > Workflow lookup for a user > set the value in pop-up window as the screenshot shows:
[image]

3.As to the email content, you could use "[%Current Item:Task Name%]has not been completed." as it is shown in the screenshot.

4.At last, set the workflow settings as start workflow automatically when an item is created.
[image]

Comment: The reason why you have not received the mail is that the workflow lacks a loop. It will only run once when an item is created, if it does not satisfy the condition, it will not send the mail. It is recommended that you use workflow 2013 to add a loop to this workflow, here is a similar case for you to refer to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/847604/sharepoint-designer-2013-loop-1.html?childToView=863805#comment-863805

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose i gave add 1 day to current item:start Date(output to Variable:end date).In Assigned to i gave my name.All the Above mentioned steps i have done.But i did not get any mail.
Anything i have to do in my task list?
Did i missed anything?